# How Do I Vary Markers in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I tried to input a list as the marker parameter but I keep receiving an error that states:

> ValueError: Unrecognized marker style ['*', 'o', '*', '*', '*', '*',
>   'o', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', 'o', '*', 'o', '*', '*', '*',
>   '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', 'o', '*', '*', 'o', '*', '*', 'o', '*',
>   '*', '*', 'o', '*', '*', '*', 'o', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', 'o', '*',
>   'o', '*', 'o', '*', '*', '*', '*', 'o', 'o', '*', 'o', '*', '*', '*',
>   'o', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', 'o', '*',
>   'o', 'o', 'o', '*', 'o', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*',
>   '*', '*', '*', '*', 'o', '*', '*', '*', '*', 'o', '*', '*', '*', '*',
>   '*', '*', '*', 'o', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*',
>   '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', 'o', '*', '*', '*', 'o', '*', '*', 'o', 'o',
>   'o', '*', 'o', 'o', 'o', '*', 'o', '*', '*', '*', 'o', '*', '*', '*',
>   'o', '*', 'o', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', 'o', 'o', '*',
>   '*', '*', '*', '*', 'o', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*',
>   '*', '*', 'o', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', 'o',
>   '*', '*', '*', '*', 'o', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', 'o', '*', '*', '*',
>   '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', 'o', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*',
>   '*', '*', '*', 'o', '*', '*', '*', 'o', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*',
>   '*', '*', '*']

here is the code:

```
pure_accuracy_rate,report,y_pred,test_labels,test_data,neigh = nearest_neighbors(raw_data,nlabels)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')


plot_vars = ["SIO2","FEOT","MGO"]


x1,y1,z1 = [test_data[:,chemicals.index(x)] for x in plot_vars]
cmap = {1:"red",2:"green",3:"blue",4:"orange"}
hit_shapes = {True:"*",False:"o"}

hit_mat = [y_pred[i] == test_labels[i] for i in range(len(test_labels))]
hit_shapes_mat = [hit_shapes[i] for i in hit_mat]
rock_colors = [cmap[x] for x in test_labels]


ax.scatter(x1, y1, zs=z1, c=rock_colors, marker=hit_shapes_mat)

ax.set_xlabel(plot_vars[0])
ax.set_ylabel(plot_vars[1])
ax.set_zlabel(plot_vars[2])
```

Is there a way to provide a marker list in matplotlib?

Comment: Short answer: No, as per the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter). Scatter does not take a list as an input for marker style.  You can, however, parse up your data itself into groups and plot with a single relevant marker style, rather than parse the marker style (which it looks like you are trying to do).  It'll be cleaner, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently, it is not possible and you have to manually split your dataset into different marker groups